# Commonsware camera preview demo: no preview after device on/off

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, commonsware

I see a bug: when the camera is in preview mode, and the user presses on/off, the camera preview stops and does not start.

An obvious suggestion is to see what other people do; I have consulted
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/
and I see that this demo has the same bug (**Android 4.0.3**).

A direct link to the java source:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java

QUESTION: how can one fix the bug? The preview mode must be working even after device on/off.

UPD: The bug does not show if I first change to another Activity and press On/Off on that Activity.

UPD2: After on/off, startPreview() is invoked, but I see a message from the system:

```
D/@@    (13428): startPreview() cameraConfigured=true camera=android.hardware.Camera@412f66f0
E/CamHw ( 2135): preview window is NULL!
```

which means that something bad does happen in depths of the system (although the message may be device-specific).

UDP3: after on/off, **no** method from `surfaceCallback` is invoked. Maybe this makes the difference.

UPD4: [seen not exactly at this camera demo] if you switch to a different application (by long-pressing HOME and choosing from the list) and then switch back, the camera works again.

Comment: As you can tell by reading [the repository's `README`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid), that repository has been discontinued. I have since moved onto maintaining [the CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), which seems to handle this case fine.

Comment: Well, it's a bad news that the code for one of the best Android books is discontinued. Anyway, what exactly did you do to handle this? The library is a big place, I would really appreciate a pointer to the file and function.

Comment: "Well, it's a bad news that the code for one of the best Android books is discontinued" -- the book's contents were folded into _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_. "Anyway, what exactly did you do to handle this?" -- beats me. I tightened up lots of things compared to that old book sample. I haven't a clue which one of those things would have impacted the behavior that you're seeing. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution, but a workaround:
invoke setContentView() in onResume().

It can be either

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);
    // ...
}
```

or

```
private View cachedContentView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cachedContentView = doCreateContentView(getLayoutInflater());
    // ...
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(cachedContentView);
    // ...
}
```

Both of them work.

I still have no idea what causes the problem and what is *the* difference between the original [example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java) and the [library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera).